# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Python Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to redirect the `python` and `django` websites from `http` to `https`.
When I'm using the `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` in `settings.py`,
I'm getting the folder structure:

[image]

Comment: what server are you using? what are your server settings? it looks like your server isn't configured correctly for https connections.

Comment: Are you including SecurityMiddleware?

Comment: Usually HTTP to HTTPS redirection happens at the web server layer (NGINX, APACHE, etc.) not Django

Comment: @dirkgroten, i'm using the Apache server.

Comment: @FilippoLauria, Yes, I'm using.

Comment: then you need to show us your apache server configuration, especially the part where you tell it how to handle requests on port 443

Answer (score 0):

Are you using apache?

Try this on your .htacess inside www folder.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I put this code in .htaccess. after using we are getting the error:-This page isn’t working
healthcare800.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

supposing that:

1. you are using `apache2`;
2. you are starting from the `default-ssl.conf` file which, if you are using a `debian-like` distro, is located in the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available`;
3. you are serving your django application using `mod_wsgi`, having modified your `default-ssl.conf` as described in [this howto](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

you could try defining a permanent redirect to https in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` directive, always in your `default-ssl.conf`, as shown below:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName your-server.name
        Redirect permanent / https://your-server.name
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName your-server.name
        ...
```